# New Page error using Multicell of the library Python PyFPDF

Tags: python, pyfpdf

I am creating a program that generates a translation sheet for a language. It uses the python FPDF module. I utilise `pdf.multicell()` to create a page with two columns for the English word, and then the foreign equivalent

I am using `pdf.set_auto_page_break()` to create  a new page whenever I reach the page limit. However, I am experiencing some problems with this.

The new page is always created after one line has been written on a new page. This means that I have mismatched translations, and lots of empty whitepsace.

This is my code:

```py
data = [['le bus', 'the bus'], ['le train', 'the train'], ['la gare', 'the train station']] etc

def write_to_pdf(data):
    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.set_auto_page_break(True, 2)
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.add_font('DejaVu', '', 'filepath/font', uni=True)
    pdf.set_font('DejaVu', '', 14)
    
    pdf.cell(200, 10, txt = title,ln = 1, align = 'C')
    pdf.cell(200, 10, txt = subtitle,ln = 2, align = 'C')
    pdf.set_font('DejaVu', '', 10)

    for section in data:
        try:
            top = pdf.y
    
            offset = pdf.x + 100

            pdf.multi_cell(100,10,section[0],0,'L')

            pdf.y = top

            pdf.x = offset 
           
            pdf.multi_cell(100,10,section[1],0,'R')

        except:
            pass

    pdf.output("Output.pdf")
```

And this is the result

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2][image: Page 3]

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

I think that the explanation of the problem is that before you save the `y` with the instruction: `top=pdf.y` and after you execute the instruction:

```
pdf.multi_cell(100,10,section[0],0,'L')
```

so when the bottom of the page is reached `y` value is high (near 300 mm) so the adding of a new `multi_cell` of 10 mm causes the creation of a new page.
The `multi_cell` which contains the sentence `òu est-ce que tu va ?` is placed at the top of the second page.
After this, the program executes the instruction `pdf.y=top` so the cursor is moved to the bottom of the second page where is inserted the new `multi_cell` with the english translation `where are you going ?`, but this is placed in the third page as you can see in your PDF file.

The solution is to add a `if` condition to test the value of `y` before to set its value. All changes are showed by the following code (which is your `write_to_pdf` function modified):

```
def write_to_pdf(data):
    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.set_auto_page_break(True, 2)
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.add_font('DejaVu', '', 'filepath/font', uni=True)
    pdf.set_font('DejaVu', '', 14)
    
    pdf.cell(200, 10, txt = title,ln = 1, align = 'C')
    pdf.cell(200, 10, txt = subtitle,ln = 2, align = 'C')
    pdf.set_font('DejaVu', '', 10)

    for section in data:
        try:
            top = pdf.y
    
            offset = pdf.x + 100

            pdf.multi_cell(100,10,section[0],0,'L')

            # ---> add this if <--- 
            if pdf.y > top:
                # we are always in the same page
                pdf.y = top
            else:
                # creation of a new page => y must be go back of the
                # height of a multi_cell (that is 10)
                pdf.y -= 10 

            pdf.x = offset 
           
            pdf.multi_cell(100,10,section[1],0,'R')

        except:
            pass

    pdf.output("Output.pdf")
```

I have tried the code on my system and seems working correctly.

---

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75866564/pyfpdf-autopagebreak-causes-that-only-one-row-is-per-page) is an other post with an analog problem but where it is used the method `cell()` instead of `multi_cell()`.